# Pending promise state using javascript fetch api with java spark (POST request)

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js, fetch-api, spark-java

I am trying to use ES6's fetch api to post some login data to a java spark server. The GET requests work perfectly, but when I try to POST something, the Promise on the client side stays 'pending'. I checked, and the server receives the request body, and parses it to an object. Using postman, it also returns true or false, so I think something is wrong with the CORS setup. I'm new to that, so i jut let * through, thinking it should work. I am using VueJS, but i don't think that really matters here, thought I'd add this info, maybe it helps. I will post the code below.

JS:

```
methods: {
    login: function () {
        data = '"perfectly valid json string"'
        this.postData('http://te.st/login', data)
    },
    postData: function(url, data){
        return fetch(url, {
            body: data,
            method: 'POST',
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (result){
            app.response = result
        })
    }
}
```

Java:

```
private static void enableCORS(final String origin, final String methods, final String headers) {

    options("/*", (request, response) -> {

        String accessControlRequestHeaders = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        if (accessControlRequestHeaders != null) {
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", accessControlRequestHeaders);
        }

        String accessControlRequestMethod = request.headers("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        if (accessControlRequestMethod != null) {
            response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", accessControlRequestMethod);
        }

        return "OK";
    });

    before((request, response) -> {
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        response.header("Access-Control-Request-Method", methods);
        response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", headers);
        response.type("application/json");
    });
}
```

(called in the code as `enableCORS("*","GET,POST","Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");` )

And the endpoint:

```
post("/login", (req, res) -> {
        boolean ret = dao.checkLogin(gson.fromJson(req.body(), User.class));
        return gson.toJson(ret);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're posting to `http://te.st`, but the server is listening to `/login`. Shouldn't you be posting to `http://te.st/login`?

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. Im posting to /login